# Is there a possibility to deploy headless CMS on CDN?

Tags: deployment, content-management-system, next.js, cdn, headless-cms

I am using the [NextJS](https://nextjs.org/) JavaScript library.

Is it possible to deploy a headless CMS such as [Strapi](https://strapi.io/) on a CDN since the website should be generated static?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned on Strapi homepage :

"You can now generate pages at deployment time and serve them over a CDN (...)".

Static pages need to be generated during deployment and then send over to a CDN (AWS S3 + AWS Cloudfront for example).

I suggest you read the full documentation :
https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/deployment/amazon-aws.html

Answer (score 0):

this is the most weird question I ever asked, the Strapi is a web app that requires a node server to be run at, so obviously it is not possible to serve it on the CDN (as the CDN is a serverless solution that may serve only static files)